# Releasing media player in Android ViewPager on swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-mediaplayer

**CONTEXT:**
I have one activity, 4 fragments and a viewPager (each page consists of one fragment). Each fragment contains a list of short sounds (max 5 seconds each). The expected behavior is: if the user clicks on a sound on a certain page and the sound did not finish playing, if the user swipes to another page, the media player will be released, thus the sound will stop playing.

**ISSUE:**
When swiping left or right, the method onPause or onStop are not called (since the viewPager by definition loads the current, the previous and the next page), thus the media player playing the sound from the last page does not stop on swipe.

**RESEARCH:**
I have searched a lot on multiple posts, related to `onPageChangeListener`, `setOffScreenPageLimit`, set MediaPlayer not in fragment but in the activity (not possible in my case, since I have lists of sounds with adapter). Here are some links that I researched but did not solve my problem: [ViewPager swipe previous sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227194/viewpager-swipe-previous-sound), [Multiple video players in viewpager in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728695/multiple-video-players-in-viewpager-in-android), [Android MediaPlayer on ViewPager blocking UI transition and no callback for initial page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416019/android-mediaplayer-on-viewpager-blocking-ui-transition-and-no-callback-for-init), [How to handle MediaPlayer object inside a fragment inside view pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810042/how-to-handle-mediaplayer-object-inside-a-fragment-inside-view-pager), [Using Viewpager with MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601226/using-viewpager-with-mediaplayer)

**SUGGESTIONS?**: if you have any suggestions on how to tackle this issue, it would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `Callback` interface on your `MainActivity` with a method `onPageChanged()` like this:

```
public interface Callback {
    void onPageChanged();
}
```

Then, you can use this `OnPageChangeListener`:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    private int currentPage = 0;

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(currentPage);

        if (fragment instanceof Callback &&
                currentPage != position) {
            ((Callback)adapter.getItem(currentPage)).onPageChanged();
        }
        currentPage = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

Each and every Fragment in your ViewPager can be created like this:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment implements MainActivity.Callback {

    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageChanged() {
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        // You can do more things here
    }
}
```

After doing that, every time that you change the Fragment on the ViewPager it will be calling the `onPageChanged` method on the previous Fragment, and in there you can release your media player and do any other operation that you require.

Answer (score 1):

Consider you making the fragment itself an [`OnPageChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html). Then you can set the listener when you attach the page. This will allow you to pass the page change information to the fragment. You are allowed to have more than one `OnPageChangeListener`. Hope that helps.

EDIT:

Consider something like this.

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    ViewPager pager;

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged (int state){
         // reset the player if needed. you can do this since player object is in this class
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
        pager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(ViewPagerId);
        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
        ....
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView (){
        ....
        pager.removeOnPageChangeListener(this);
        ....

    }
}
```

Comment: You say "you can set the listener when you attach the page", but all my 4 pages (the 4 fragments) are added through an adapter. Can you please offer a code snippet clarifying your suggestion?

Comment: unfortunatelly it does not work. I used ```implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener``` in fragments but the methods are not triggered...

Answer (score 1):

```
private int currentPos = 0;
private int prevPos = -1;
```

global variable

I am getting same problem. I have take two method play and stop in fragment. and call below code in `onPageSelected(int position)`

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        prevPos = currentPos;
                        currentPos = position;
                        MyFragment fragment = (MainFragment) getChildFragmentManager().
                                findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPagerVideo + ":" + prevPos);
                        if (fragment != null) {
                            fragment.stop();
                        }
                        fragment = (MyFragment) getChildFragmentManager().
                                findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + currentPos);
                        if (fragment != null) {
                            fragment.play(mListUrl.get(position));
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Dheerubhai Bansal, the above code solved your problem? or by using it,  you are still facing the issue?

Comment: My problem is solved. I am playing video in fragment of ViewPager.

Comment: I have used ViewPager within fragment. If you are using ViewPager within activty use getSupportFragmentManaager instaed of getChildFragmentManager.

Comment: Dheerubhai, thank you! I studied a little bit your answer, I try to understand how I can adapt it in my case where I use the viewPager in an activity (while you used it in a fragment). Also, I was wondering if you could have written the code above without the first "new Thread(new Runnable() {.....}).start()" block. Wouldn't have worked directly stepping into "try {....} catch (...) {}"? PS: I upvoted your answer, but my reputation is just 1, I have just started with stackoverflow.